# Protecting a Xml file

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I'm fairly new to coding, and I just got help figuring out how to create a Xml file; now I want to know, is there a way to protect my Xml file from being edited?

I'm making a simple Command Prompt game, and I'm going to include an Xml file for info storage purposes. Although I don't want the user to be able to change the info contained in the file.. Is there a way to achieve this? It doesn't need to be extensive at this time, due to the program only being a small project.

Anyway, I'm making the program with Visual Studio Pro 2010, and I'm coding it in C#.
Thank you, for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

the standard way to verify that parts of your xml has not been modified is to use [XML_Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature)

[this msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shows how this is done with dotnet4

Comment: Thanks, this way seems very confusing, but I may figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I would embed your XML file as a resource of your console application's assembly. The XML file will exist as an embedded resource and not as a seperate file that the user could potentially change. If the user isn't meant to edit a configuration file, don't even let him see it, modify it, or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

look at this topic [decrypt and encrypt](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/encrypting-decrypting-string/)

i have created my own Encrypter class based from this classes. then you can create it for yourself for next use

Comment: I'll take a look at it, although I'm not sure I can Encypt.. I tried making a program that runs: File.Encypt("test.xml");
And I get an IOException: "This request is not supported."

Comment: i never used this method. but now i have looked it. but don't liked it :-). i advise my link. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could simply compress it, if you don't need a high level of security. You could use a standard format (ZIP, CAB), or just deflate the stream and store it as a binary file. See the doc and examples about this here: [DeflateStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You can't prevent anyone from editing your xml file but you can encrypt your xml file to protect your data.

Comment: How would I go about encrypting it then?

Comment: search google for encryption library in c# and just simply use to encrypt ur xml to give some sort of protection.